# Placement of Else in a nested If

Tags: php

I am a PHP noob working through the tutorials and I found an issue with nested If Else that I don't understand.  I have an outer if with a series of inner if's.  And, I have an else I wanted associated with the outer if.  My original code never executed the else, which should occur if the outer if was false.  The original code was:

```
if (!($result["name"] & $result["age"] & $result["email"]))
{
    if (!$result["name"]) 
    {
        echo("Name must be supplied.<br>");
    }
    if (!$result["age"])
    {
        echo("Age must be a number between 1 and 120.<br>");
    }
    if (!$result["email"])
    {
        echo("E-Mail is not valid.<br>");
    }
 }
 else 
 {
     echo("User input is valid.<br/>");
 }
```

As I said, the else was never executed.  However, I moved the else inside the brackets and it worked.  The working code is:

```
if (!($result["name"] & $result["age"] & $result["email"]))
{
    if (!$result["name"]) 
    {
        echo("Name must be supplied.<br>");
    }
    if (!$result["age"])
    {
        echo("Age must be a number between 1 and 120.<br>");
    }
    if (!$result["email"])
    {
        echo("E-Mail is not valid.<br>");
    }
    else 
    {
        echo("User input is valid.<br/>");
    }
}
```

This seems to be wrong to me.  Probably just some noob mistake but I cannot figure it out.  Thanks for your help...RG

Comment: Are you meaning a bitwise and (`&`) instead of a boolean and (`&&`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AND` comparison operator or `&&` comparison operator instead of `&` bitwise operator.

For a quick review of   PHP operators go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp)

Comment: I do understand now.  When I was typing the If statement, a thought went through my head that I should verify the operator.  But, since the syntax checker didn't flag me, I let it go to my chagrin.  Thanks for the help...RG

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
if (!($result["name"] & $result["age"] & $result["email"]))
```

with this

```
if (!($result["name"] && $result["age"] && $result["email"]))
```

Its two & signs not only one.

Comment: Well, that surely did fix it.  Thank you very much.  Can you explain what was going on?  I wonder why I wasn't getting a syntax error.  More than that, I wonder why the code worked at all that way.  Thanks...RG

Comment: You were using a bitwise operator instead of AND operator.

Comment: Okay, I see now.  A few echos and I realize that the outer if was always returning TRUE.  So, I understand what was going on.  Thanks so much for your help...RG

Answer (score 0):

on your first if . if you want to execute it

if your name,age and email is empty or not set

you need atleast to put `!` on every `$result[]` and change your `&` to `&&`

```
if (!($result["name"] && !$result["age"] && !$result["email"]))
```

try to use this code..

Comment: The code u supplied would work if the $result["name"] is not null and the age and email are null.

Comment: This makes sense since I didn't include the entire program.  The $result was the return from a filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, $filters), so the check was based on fliter validation.  Thanks...RG